# Symfony Doctrine2 Doesn't insert an available ID

Tags: php, sql, oracle, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a new problem related to Doctrine2 and Oracle...

I migrated an application from Symfony1 to symfony2. When I insert a new entry in the production database with Doctrine2, I get the error "ORA-00001: unique constraint violated". It tries to insert with the ID 1, if I try again it tries to insert with ID 2 etc...

Here is how I setup my entity :

```
    <?php

namespace EspaceApprenti\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * ApprenticeMark
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="APPRENTICE_MARK", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IDX_8582BCF7105754FC", columns={"FK_BRANCH"}), @ORM\Index(name="IDX_8582BCF7C9387C17", columns={"FK_YEAR"}), @ORM\Index(name="IDX_8582BCF73B451C64", columns={"FK_MARKTYPE"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="EspaceApprenti\UserBundle\Entity\ApprenticeMarkRepository")
 */
class ApprenticeMark
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="COEFFICIENT", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     */
    private $coefficient;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ID", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="RESULT", type="decimal", precision=2, scale=1, nullable=false)
     */
    private $result;

    /**
     * @var \ApprenticeBranch
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ApprenticeBranch")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="FK_BRANCH", referencedColumnName="ID")
     * })
     */
    private $fkBranch;

    /**
     * @var \ApprenticeYear
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ApprenticeYear")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="FK_YEAR", referencedColumnName="ID", onDelete="CASCADE")
     * })
     */
    private $fkYear;

    /**
     * @var \ApprenticeMarktype
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ApprenticeMarktype")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="FK_MARKTYPE", referencedColumnName="ID")
     * })
     */
    private $fkMarktype;



    /**
     * Set coefficient
     *
     * @param integer $coefficient
     * @return ApprenticeMark
     */
    public function setCoefficient($coefficient)
    {
        $this->coefficient = $coefficient;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get coefficient
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getCoefficient()
    {
        return $this->coefficient;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set result
     *
     * @param integer $result
     * @return ApprenticeMark
     */
    public function setResult($result)
    {
        $this->result = $result;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get result
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getResult()
    {
        return $this->result;
    }

    /**
     * Set fkBranch
     *
     * @param \EspaceApprenti\UserBundle\Entity\ApprenticeBranch $fkBranch
     * @return ApprenticeMark
     */
    public function setFkBranch(\EspaceApprenti\UserBundle\Entity\ApprenticeBranch $fkBranch = null)
    {
        $this->fkBranch = $fkBranch;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fkBranch
     *
     * @return \EspaceApprenti\UserBundle\Entity\ApprenticeBranch 
     */
    public function getFkBranch()
    {
        return $this->fkBranch;
    }

    /**
     * Set fkYear
     *
     * @param \EspaceApprenti\UserBundle\Entity\ApprenticeYear $fkYear
     * @return ApprenticeMark
     */
    public function setFkYear(\EspaceApprenti\UserBundle\Entity\ApprenticeYear $fkYear = null)
    {
        $this->fkYear = $fkYear;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fkYear
     *
     * @return \EspaceApprenti\UserBundle\Entity\ApprenticeYear 
     */
    public function getFkYear()
    {
        return $this->fkYear;
    }

    /**
     * Set fkMarktype
     *
     * @param \EspaceApprenti\UserBundle\Entity\ApprenticeMarktype $fkMarktype
     * @return ApprenticeMark
     */
    public function setFkMarktype(\EspaceApprenti\UserBundle\Entity\ApprenticeMarktype $fkMarktype = null)
    {
        $this->fkMarktype = $fkMarktype;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fkMarktype
     *
     * @return \EspaceApprenti\UserBundle\Entity\ApprenticeMarktype 
     */
    public function getFkMarktype()
    {
        return $this->fkMarktype;
    }
}
```

Here is the code of the controller :

```
public function newAction($idYear,$idYeartype)
    {
        $m = $this->getDoctrine()
                  ->getManager();

        // Get year
        $year = $m->getRepository('EspaceApprentiUserBundle:ApprenticeYear')->find($idYear);
        if (!$year) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException('Year not found');
        }
        // Get yeartype
        $yeartype = $m->getRepository('EspaceApprentiUserBundle:ApprenticeYeartype')->find($idYeartype);
        if (!$yeartype) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException('Year type not found');
        }
        // Get apprentice
        $apprentice = $m->getRepository('EspaceApprentiUserBundle:ApprenticeApprentice')->find($year->getFkApprentice()->getId());
        if (!$apprentice) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException('Apprentice type not found');
        }

        $mark = new ApprenticeMark();
        $mark->setFkYear($year);
        $form = $this->createForm(new ApprenticeMarkType($yeartype), $mark);

        $request = $this->get('request');
        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
                $form->bind($request);
                if ($form->isValid()) {
                        $m->persist($mark);
                        $m->flush();
                        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('grids_apprentice_index',array('idApprentice' => $apprentice->getId())));
                }
        }

        return $this->render('EspaceApprentiGridsBundle:Grids_Mark:new.html.twig', array('apprentice' => $apprentice, 'form' => $form->createView()));
    }
```

How do I configure Doctrine2 to get the last ID and not just increment from 1 ?
Or should I get and insert the last ID manually ?

Regards

Comment: Did you update your schema?

Comment: Yes I did : "php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force"

Comment: I also have the following error when I try to validate the schema : [Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.
[Database] FAIL - The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file.            Even if I do a update --dump-sql before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670471/database-fail-the-database-schema-is-not-in-sync-with-the-current-mapping-file

Comment: And what is output of schema update force?

Comment: Updating database schema...
Database schema updated successfully! "8" queries were executed

Comment: Every time it is 8 queries were ... ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Yes it is "8 queries" everytime.

Comment: If you update and then again with no changes of entity files, 0 queries should be executed. Dump your SQL and try put this code via phpmyadmin and execute it.

Comment: I'm using Oracle 11G I don't know how to execute it :/

Comment: All the executed queries are foreign keys. "ALTER TABLE APPRENTICE_YEAR MODIFY (FK_APPRENTICE  NUMBER(20) DEFAULT NULL);", "ALTER TABLE APPRENTICE_BRANCH MODIFY (FK_YEARTYPE  NUMBER(20) DEFAULT NULL);" etc... But in Oracle the values are correct : name : FK_APPRENTICE type : NUMBER(20,0) default : NULL

Comment: And what is your controller code?

Comment: I added the controller code in the post.

Comment: Could you provide your entity mapping completely? It's not just id; I guess there is a small typo or extra space somewhere in your mapping, specially if you have any relational field

Comment: @Servietsky is there any specific reason that you defined the indexes in source code? I mean why don't you let it be created by doctrine?

Comment: I never set them myself. The doctrine2 mapping import command did this. I found the solution below. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. Apparently my SEQUENCES in Oracle were not up to date, so I had to manually update them.