# TEST environment only: The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

There are some similar questions regarding to this issue but I haven't seen anything in particular to TEST environment and sqlite. I cannot validate schema for TEST environment which uses sqlite however I can validate schemas for DEV environment which uses mysql. Does anyone know what could be the reason and the possible solution? Whole application works fine in both DEV and TEST environments though. Only my phing and CI build is broken.

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force --env=test
Updating database schema...
Database schema updated successfully! "9" queries were executed
php app/console doctrine:schema:validate --env=test
[Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.
[Database] FAIL - The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file.
```

---

**UPDATE**

I'm adding sqldump result to see if anyone spots anything wrong with it. The only thing I can say is, I have two bundles. `country` below is coming from `frontendbundle` but the `user` entity is missing which is defined in `backendbundle`.

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql --env=test
DROP INDEX UNIQ_5373C9665E237E06;
DROP INDEX UNIQ_5373C966D1F4EB9A;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE __temp__country AS SELECT id, name, flag FROM country;
DROP TABLE country;
CREATE TABLE country (id INTEGER NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, flag VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id));
INSERT INTO country (id, name, flag) SELECT id, name, flag FROM __temp__country;
DROP TABLE __temp__country;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_5373C9665E237E06 ON country (name);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_5373C966D1F4EB9A ON country (flag);
```

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/16550985/277106

Comment: Yes I saw that before and many moe.

Comment: Does the MySQL dump differ from the database structure then?

Comment: @BentCoder This can happen when you set entity field type as `datetimetz` in mapping configuration,,

Comment: Guys I added sqldump above.

Comment: Have you registered `BackendBundle`? Also, in case you are using multiple entity managers, you have to map each bundle to an entity manager, otherwise the bundle entities won't be recognized.

Comment: Bundles are registered otherwise DEV wouldn't work either. Same applies to you EM question. Whole app is fine.

Comment: Check if there is something configured in the other environments' files (`config_dev.yml`, `config_prod.yml`) which is missing in the test environment's `config_test.yml`

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this @BentCoder? More than 3 years later I'm facing the same issue...

Comment: Manualy name your indexes and unique constrains within `@ORM\Table(.....)` annotation.

Comment: Thanks @BentCoder, but in my case this happens on a join table so can't annotate the index unfortunately.

Comment: oh and it only happens with sqlite