# The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file (but it is !)

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony4

I just fixed some things in my code. I'm now trying to validate my schema

> php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate

Doctrine tells me my mapping is correct but my database schema is not. So I'm doing a

> schema:update --dump-sql

which results in the same ALTER again and again, that I already performed many times.

Here is the ALTER :

```
 ALTER TABLE migration_versions CHANGE version version VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL;
```

I did it (with --force), the entity is reflecting the change already :

```
**
 * MigrationVersions
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="migration_versions")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class MigrationVersions
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="version", type="string", length=14, nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $version;
```

I am correct right ? its varchar, lenght 14...

And so is it in my database
[image]

I don't think Im making a mistake here but I may be missing something.

Comment: This is probably a bug... I don't have time right now to make a ticket to the Doctrine team about that, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Have you already verified that the `server_version` in the doctrine config file is correct? (`config/packages/doctrine.yaml` in symfony5)

It happened to me that I was using MariaDB (`version 10.4.11-MariaDB - Source distribution`) and in the file `doctrine.yaml` the `server_version` parameter had the value `5.7`.
After I corrected that, the error no longer occurred.

Also you can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670471/database-fail-the-database-schema-is-not-in-sync-with-the-current-mapping-file/41875470)

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer ! I have to say I'm not working on that project anymore but I take note of what you said, if I ever encounter that problem again :)

Comment: No problem. Sooner or later someone else will come here with the same problem. Thanks for the upvote :)