# Symfony [ERROR] The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file?

Tags: symfony

i have updated from symfony version 3.4 to 5.2, i am trying to update the database too using `doctrine` , when i try to fix the database schema i got this error :

```
[ERROR] The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file.
```

here is the full log :

[image]

the steps i have done is :

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force --complete --dump-sql

php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate
```

then :

```
    php bin/console doctrine:migrations:generate 
    
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:execute --up 'DoctrineMigrations\Version20210825153011'
    
    [notice] Executing DoctrineMigrations\Version20210825153011 up
    [warning] Migration DoctrineMigrations\Version20210825153011 was executed but did not result in any SQL statements.
    [notice] finished in 59ms, used 26M memory, 1 migrations executed, 0 sql queries
```

is it possible to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Your migration didn't do anything: 1 migration executed, 0 SQL queries

Did the command (doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql) generate some SQL ? If not try to start from a new database and generate a full migration of it, and compare it with all of your migration to see if there is any change

Furthermore, if you want to migrate your database do :

> php bin/console doctrine:migrations:generate (check the generated
> migrations to see if there is any SQL query created)
>
> php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate (it execute all
> migrations)

Edit : As asked

> bin/console doctrine:database:drop
>
> bin/console doctrine:database:create
>
> bin/console doctrine:schema:create
>
> bin/console doctrine:schema:validate

With these commands, you can start from a fresh db in sync with your mapping.

Comment: so for example my old db is db1 , i should create new db2 and migrate it with db1 ? what about the records in db1

Comment: It's only to validate your mapping if doctrine can generate a migration for a db2 that is valid, you can compare this migration with your old migration for db1 and see if doctrine generator miss something

Comment: Sorry, no.

Doctrine is an ORM it uses your mapping information on your class to generate SQL queries. 

Doctrine migrations are generated from a difference between your mapping and the database. If you make a change in your database (from PHPMyAdmin), Doctrine migrations can generate wrong queries. Also, it can ignore the manual change but said that there is an error in your mapping.

Your mapping and migrations can be good, but with some manual intervention, you desync the database. 

It can also happen with old versions of Doctrine because all mapping isn't transformed in SQL query.

Comment: okay , let say i need to dump empty database from entities , as u mention above it is possible , can you update your answer to drop the current database and create new one with entities tables using Doctrine , so i will have fresh database with correct scheme and mapping . then ill try to dump the old records

Comment: Many thanks , i did applied the editing of create db , i still get same problem ` [ERROR] The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file.`

Comment: other post which could help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16550985/6614155